# I need to convert audio files using ffmpeg but i got error

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I wanna convert an mp3 file to wav file but I can't.
 I try converting mp3 file to other formats too but I always get an error .
Maybe my implementation of FFmpeg has problem if you how to import the FFmpeg library tell me in the comment too. 
I search a lot but I can't find solution maybe my FFmpeg command code has a problem. if you know how to deal whit it please help me.
this is my code.

```
String s = " -i " + musicDbs.get(0).musicPath +" -vn -ar 44100 -b:a 192k "+ dir.getPath();
// s =  -i /storage/emulated/0/Doto30/FX/Pishro_Ft_Hichkas_Divoone.mp3 -vn -ar 44100 -b:a 192k /storage/emulated/0/Doto30/.final_audio.wav
String[]cmd = s.split(" ");
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                String s1 = message;
                Toast.makeText(context, s1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Build has been successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        if (ffmpeg.isFFmpegCommandRunning()) {
            ffmpeg.killRunningProcesses();
        }
    }
```

but i got this error

```
ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain- 
android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect -- 
sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable- 
libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable- 
fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded- 
tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared - 
-enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config -- 
prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='- 
I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE - 
D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='- 
L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra- 
libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mp3 @ 0xf6829000] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 116058.   
[mjpeg @ 0xf687e400] Changing bps to 8
[mp3 @ 0xf6829000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/Doto30/FX/Pishro_Ft_Hichkas_Divoone.mp3':
Metadata:
  album_artist    : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  album           : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  artist          : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  composer        : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  disc            : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  genre           : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  title           : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  lyrics-eng      : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  track           : 1865
  encoded_by      : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  TOPE            : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  copyright       : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  TIT1            : [3DaMusic.Ir]
  date            : 2014
Duration: 00:03:48.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 132 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 530x533, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Metadata:
  title           : [www.shiraz-song.ir]
  comment         : Cover (front)
[NULL @ 0xf6829600] Unable to find a suitable output format for ''
: Invalid argument
```

if you can help me.

Comment: beautiful thing about ffmpeg is your can execute it directly on the command line in a terminal as a direct and much easier way to get the syntax of input and output working ... once your command line runs OK giving good results then put those settings into your programmatic calls to ffmpeg ... I suggest you run ffmpeg from a terminal first

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but at all its not helpful

Comment: the error says the syntax is wrong ... I suggest you play with various syntax options by executing the command line ffmpeg directly in a terminal then once its working use the new found syntax in your code

Comment: :| :| :| :| :| :|